# AngualrJS: Why isn't Component scope binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, components, createjs

I have come across an issue and created a [JSFiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/503jfL34/1/)

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.component("bar", {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                        $scope.msg = "Hello";
            setTimeout(function(){
                $scope.msg = "Goodbye";
                alert($scope.msg);
            }, 3000)
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <bar>
        {{ $parent.msg }}
    </bar>
</body>
```

As you can see I have a scope variable (msg) that I am updating after I do some work (setTimeout in this case).
There seems to be only one-way binding in the HTML, because "Goodbye" is never rendered to the view when the component's scope is updated.

Am I correct to be using `$parent`? Have I got my scope all wrong? Am I handling transclusion properly?

**Edit**

I should say that `setTimeout` is only a example, in my real world case I am trying to add components for http://www.createjs.com/
Instead of `setTimeout` I was actually adding a 'complete' event listener to a PreLoadJS `LoadQueue` http://www.createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/classes/LoadQueue.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason is you are doing this inside `setTimeout` which is not in angular context. Any time you update scope outside of angular context you need to notify angular to run a digest to update view

Angular provides a service `$timeout` that takes care of this for you.

Try:

```
controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $timeout) {
        $scope.msg = "Hello";
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.msg = "Goodbye";
            alert($scope.msg);
        }, 3000)
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/503jfL34/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers - setTimeout was just an example, in my real case I am adding a event listener, but I guess the same applies it is a non-angular context.
I will Edit my question to add more detail about my actual case.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a Angular context when working with a non-Angular library?

Comment: Use `$scope.$apply()` when updating scope outside

Comment: Ahh okay - So now I've updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/503jfL34/3/ to use `$scope.$apply()` and it now works as I want.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$timeout` service instead of the raw `setTimeout` function.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.component("bar", {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $timeout) {
            $scope.msg = "Hello";
            //Use $timeout
            $timeout(function(){
            //
            //setTimeout(function(){
                $scope.msg = "Goodbye";
                //alert($scope.msg);
            }, 3000)
    }
});
```

The `$timeout` service is the AngularJS wrapper for the `setTimeout` function. It returns promises and is integrated with the AngularJS framework digest cycle.

For more information, see [AngularJS $timeout Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

Answer (score 0):

using `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` will fix your problem as the other answers mention but using `$parent` is never a good idea. It makes your code very fragile. For example try putting an ng-if around your `{{$parent.msg}}` binding and notice that it breaks (http://jsfiddle.net/yagn5v0s/)

A better solution would be to use component bindings to pass something out of the component. e.g.

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.component("bar", {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    bindings: {
      msg: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $timeout) {
      var self = this;
      self.msg = "Hello";
      $timeout(function(){
        self.msg = "Goodbye";
        alert(self.msg);
      }, 3000)
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <bar msg="vm.myMsg">
        {{ vm.myMsg }}
    </bar>
</body>
```

working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rc8zs4nk/